# meta-programming and the substitute function in R

Tags: r, metaprogramming, substitution

```
f <- function() {
  x <- 6 + 4
  substitute(x)
}
f()
```

The above will output:

```
[1] 10
```

However, the below:

```
x <- 6 + 4
substitute(x)
```

outputs:

```
x
```

Why are they different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@akrun's answer demonstrates *how* to get it to resolve, but I think the answer to your question of "*Why?"* is in [`?substitute`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/substitute), where it says in the Details:

> If it is an ordinary variable, its value is substituted, ***unless `env` is     `.GlobalEnv` in which case the symbol is left unchanged.***

(Emphasis mine.) When you are executing this on the default prompt `>`, you are in the global environment. Not so in your first example, within the function's namespace. (As to *"Why did R-core decide on this behavior?"*, I do not think I am qualified to answer or even speculate.)

Comment: One reason I like questions like this on SO is that ... I didn't know this before hand, and would never have guessed that this would be the default behavior. It seems odd, but then again a couple of decades of sometimes-spiral development with backwards compatibility requirements leads to slightly inconsistent behaviors. It was likely the best choice at the time (and perhaps still is for reasons I don't understand \*shrug\*).

Comment: `substitute(X, list(X = x))` is a common usage which will work here

Answer (score 1):

The `eval`uation is not happening

```
eval(substitute(x))
#[1] 10
```

---

As @r2evans showed the documentation description, we can test it on a new environment to see this in action

```
# create the object in another environment
e1 <- new.env()
e1$x <- 6 + 4
substitute(x) # here x is looked in the global space
#x
substitute(x, env = e1) # specify the `env` and looks for the local env
#[1] 10
```